# Does Olivia Voldaren's second ability still work if I steal her in response?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Olivia Voldaren](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Olivia%20Voldaren) has the following for her second ability:

> {3}{B}{B}: Gain control of target Vampire for as long as you control Olivia Voldaren.

Meanwhile, [Merieke Ri Berit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Merieke%20Ri%20Berit) has this for her second ability:

> {T}: Gain control of target creature for as long as you control Merieke Ri Berit. When Merieke Ri Berit leaves the battlefield or becomes untapped, destroy that creature. It can't be regenerated.

My opponent activates Olivia Voldaren's second ability, targeting a vampire. In response, I activate Merieke Ri Berit's second ability to steal Olivia Voldaren. Will my opponent still gain control of the vampire?

Comment: Remember that duplicate questions are redirected to the question they have linked as "duplicate of" for anonymous users. That would certainly not work for this question, because they would get the wrong answer.

Comment: @Pablo I've edited and retracted my close vote - the question as worded before simply asked it it resolved and didn't mention what the ability was, so it was pretty easy to think it was actually the same question.

Answer (score 11):

This one is an edge case, so it's interesting. Yes, the second ability resolves, but as the player activating the ability no longer controls Olivia, the end result is similar to if it hadn't, as she is no longer under that player's control.

There's a ruling on [the gatherer page](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=olivia+voldaren) confirming this:

> If you activate Olivia Voldaren's last ability, and before that ability resolves you lose control of Olivia Voldaren, the ability will resolve with no effect. You won't gain control of the targeted Vampire.

Comment: This is because of the sentence _"for as long as you control Olivia Voldaren"_ in the ability. See rule 611.2b.

Answer (score 2):

Berit's ability resolves, stealing Olivia. Olivia's ability resolves but as the player no longer controls Olivia the vampire she targeted stays under your control.